# pgsql select for update multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following plpgsql function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION user_delete(
  IN id INT4
)
  RETURNS VOID
AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM user_role WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM user_permission WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM permission_cache WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM access WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM "user" WHERE user_id = id;
  END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Is it possible to lock rows related to used_id in all tables with a single select for update query?

Comment: Why would you need the lock? For backing up rows before deleting them?

Comment: Nope, I am just looking for recommendation, is it necessary to lock by delete or update? Can it cause problems if not locked and a parallel query updates that rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't normally *need* to use explicit locks unless you have a race condition and heavy concurrent load in your application. It's generally best to streamline write access, so that all processes access tables and rows in the same order to avoid deadlocks. The `DELETE` commands collects locks just as fast as `SELECT FOR UPDATE` does.

I don't think it is possible to do that with a single [`SELECT FOR UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE).
Just lock rows in all tables sequentially:

```
PERFORM 1 FROM user_role x WHERE x.user_id = id FOR UPDATE;
PERFORM 1 FROM user_permission x WHERE x.user_id = id FOR UPDATE;
...
```

Locks are collected "as you go" and released at the end of the transaction. Since a function is inside a transaction automatically, all locks remain at least until the end of the function.

- Inside a plpgsql function use `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT`, since you don't actually want any rows returned.
- Beware of name conflicts. I used table-qualified column names in my example.